# On the Continuity of the Jacobian of a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\phi:U\longrightarrow V$ be a diffeomorphism between the open sets $U, V\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Provided $J\phi(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U$ we have a map $$J\phi:U\longrightarrow GL_n(\mathbb R), x\mapsto J\phi(x).$$ Is this map continuous?

Above $J\phi(x)$ is the Jacobian of $\phi$.

Comment: What is your definition of "diffeomorphism". In many sources, it means a $C^1$ map with $C^1$ inverse.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be. There exist diffeomorphisms with discontinuous derivative maps. I think you desire the condition of $C^{1}$ on $\phi$.

Comment: Sure =).. in the case $\phi\in C^1$, $J\phi$ is continuous by definition right?

Comment: That is correct.